# Графические ресурсы для карт

Tags: карты, android

Доброго времени суток.
Немного глупый вопрос - где можно найти ресурсы для карт ?
[image]

Хотелось бы придерживаться стандартных иконок в оформление, но не могу их найти.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: так, как карты требуют установленного Google Maps, смею предположить, что в исходниках/ресурсах приложения Google Maps

Answer (score 1):

посмотри в каталоге **android-sdk/platforms/android-xx/data/res**

Answer (score 0):

Еще можете посмотреть [вот здесь](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)